# firefox height does not grow up but works in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have two `display: table-cell` columns. Left one has a button and it adds content to left column when clicked. And right one has text box which should grow its height with the height of left column. So, I gave some fixed height value to right column: `#step-right { height: 10px; }`.

This works fine in chrome but still having issue in firefox. I found firefox have some issue regarding `height: 100%` but could not say this is exactly the same problem. I want to solve using no JS tricks.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

```js
function step() {
  var stepLeft = document.getElementById('step-left');
  stepLeft.innerHTML = 'Step <br/>' + stepLeft.innerHTML; 
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.step-content {
  display: table;
  background-color: blue;
}

.step-bar {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

#step-left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#step-right {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.input-group {
  height: 95%;             
  display: table;
}

.input-group textarea {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="step-content">
      <div class="step-bar" id="step-left">
        <button type="button" onClick="step()">Step</button>
      </div>
      <div class="step-bar" id="step-right">
        <span class="input-group">
          <textarea></textarea>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```